# Improving speed of code on VBA that changes color of letters

Tags: performance, vba, fonts, ms-word

I'm very new to Visual Basic for Applications so this problem is confusing me a little. I wanted to create a code that would scan a word document and change the color of the letters to a certain color allocated to that particular letter, throughout the document. For example, the letters 'A' and 'a' would be a dark blue color and the letters 'B' and 'b' would be a dark green color. The code works, however it takes SO LONG. I don't know whether the code could be improved to be faster as I'm very new to this. I created this code using an example of a code that changes just one letter's color, that I found here (https://superuser.com/questions/230665/how-do-i-change-the-font-color-of-a-specific-letter-throughout-the-entire-ms-wor). The code I created was as follows:

```
Sub ChangeLetterColor()

Const LETTERA = "A"
Const ALETTER = "a"
Const LETTERB = "B"
Const BLETTER = "b"
Const LETTERC = "C"
Const CLETTER = "c"
Const LETTERD = "D"
Const DLETTER = "d"
Const LETTERE = "E"
Const ELETTER = "e"
Const éLETTER = "é"
Const èLETTER = "è"
Const LETTERF = "F"
Const FLETTER = "f"
Const LETTERG = "G"
Const GLETTER = "g"
Const LETTERH = "H"
Const HLETTER = "h"
Const LETTERI = "I"
Const ILETTER = "i"
Const LETTERJ = "J"
Const JLETTER = "j"
Const LETTERK = "K"
Const KLETTER = "k"
Const LETTERL = "L"
Const LLETTER = "l"
Const LETTERM = "M"
Const MLETTER = "m"
Const LETTERN = "N"
Const NLETTER = "n"
Const LETTERO = "O"
Const OLETTER = "o"
Const òLETTER = "ò"
Const LETTERP = "P"
Const PLETTER = "p"
Const LETTERQ = "Q"
Const QLETTER = "q"
Const LETTERR = "R"
Const RLETTER = "r"
Const LETTERS = "S"
Const SLETTER = "s"
Const LETTERT = "T"
Const TLETTER = "t"
Const LETTERU = "U"
Const ULETTER = "u"
Const LETTERV = "V"
Const VLETTER = "v"
Const LETTERW = "W"
Const WLETTER = "w"
Const LETTERX = "X"
Const XLETTER = "x"
Const LETTERY = "Y"
Const YLETTER = "y"
Const LETTERZ = "Z"
Const ZLETTER = "z"

For i = 1 To ThisDocument.Range.Characters.Count
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERA Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkBlue
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = ALETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkBlue
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERB Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = BLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERC Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdTurquoise
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = CLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdTurquoise
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERD Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdGray25
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = DLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdGray25
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERE Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdTeal
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = ELETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdTeal
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = éLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdTeal
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = èLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdTeal
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERF Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkYellow
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = FLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkYellow
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERG Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = GLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERH Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdViolet
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = HLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdViolet
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERI Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = ILETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERJ Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkRed
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = JLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkRed
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERK Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkYellow
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = KLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkYellow
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERL Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERM Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdPink
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = MLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdPink
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERN Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdGray50
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = NLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdGray50
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERO Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdYellow
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = OLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdYellow
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = òLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdYellow
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERP Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = PLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERR Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdViolet
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = RLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdViolet
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERS Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = SLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERT Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkBlue
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = TLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkBlue
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERU Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdTurquoise
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = ULETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdTurquoise
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERV Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdGray25
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = VLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdGray25
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERW Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdPink
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = WLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdPink
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERX Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdYellow
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = XLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdYellow
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERY Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = YLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTERZ Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack
End If
If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = ZLETTER Then
ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack
End If

Next

End Sub
```

I'm sorry if it's terrible but I am just a beginner, if somebody could help me it would be very appreciated. When I run this code in a macro-enabled word document, it takes well over an hour just to do a page of writing, I've tried this on multiple computers.

Answer (score 2):

There may well be a faster using VBA's object model but, at a bare minimum, I'd try this.

Since you don't need to check for other characters in each iteration once you've found the one you want, that sequence of `if` statement is pretty inefficient. I'd start by using `elseif` statatement and sorting the characters by likely frequency (vowels first and so on, depending on your language).

You may also want to cache the character, that *may* improve speed.

So something like:

```
Dim ch as String
For i = 1 To ThisDocument.Range.Characters.Count
    Ch = ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i)

    If Ch = LETTERE or Ch = ELETTER Then
        ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdTeal
    ElseIf Ch = LETTERA Or Ch = ALETTER Then
        ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkBlue
    ElseIf ...
    End If
Next
```

You might also consider the possibility of morphing all letters to the uppercase version:

```
    Ch = UCase (ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i))
```

so that each individual `If/ElseIf` section can be simplified into one check.

Comment: Not sure how much of a boost this will add, but rather than checking for both a lower and an upper case (since they both have the same end result), using Ch = StrConv(ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i), vbUpperCase) will cut down on both the number of constants to check and the number of 'or' to sort through.  Although to be honest, I've never tested to see how it would work on accented letters...

Comment: @sous2817, since the accented e is the only one there, you could always treat that as a special case _before_ doing the `UCase`.

Comment: Speaking of caching (which, yes, is the best thing here), you should be caching `ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i)` as a `Range` object, not its contents as a string (`Dim ch as Range: Set ch = ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i)`). Then you can use `ch` for both reading text and writing colors. As for `UCase`, it's actually better to use `If StrComp(ch, "A", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me with this. I did try to use this way but it kept coming up with a compile error with the (If ch =...) statements and being a beginner I couldn't figure out how to get rid of it. This did teach me a lot though and it's very appreciated. Thank you. :')

Answer (score 1):

I'm not surprised `ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i)` is slow. It should really be.

Try this:

```
Private Type ColorForLetter
  Letter As String
  ColorIndex As WdColorIndex
End Type


Public Sub ColorAllLetters(ByVal r As Range, ColorData() As ColorForLetter, ByVal MatchCase As Boolean)
  Dim i As Long

  For i = LBound(ColorData) To UBound(ColorData)
    With r.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .ClearAllFuzzyOptions

      With .Replacement
        .ClearFormatting
        .Font.ColorIndex = ColorData(i).ColorIndex
      End With

      .Execute FindText:=ColorData(i).Letter, MatchCase:=MatchCase, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
  Next
End Sub


Public Sub Test()
  Dim info(1 To 29) As ColorForLetter

  With info(1)
    .Letter = "A"
    .ColorIndex = wdDarkBlue
  End With

  With info(2)
    .Letter = "B"
    .ColorIndex = wdGreen
  End With

  'Following lines are inlined for brevity, but they do same as above

  With info(3): .Letter = "C": .ColorIndex = wdTurquoise: End With
  With info(4): .Letter = "D": .ColorIndex = wdGray25: End With

  With info(5): .Letter = "E": .ColorIndex = wdTeal: End With
  With info(6): .Letter = ChrW$(&HC9&): .ColorIndex = wdTeal: End With 'My locale does not support this letter as a literal
  With info(7): .Letter = ChrW$(&HC8&): .ColorIndex = wdTeal: End With 'My locale does not support this letter as a literal
  With info(8): .Letter = "F": .ColorIndex = wdDarkYellow: End With
  With info(9): .Letter = "G": .ColorIndex = wdRed: End With
  With info(10): .Letter = "H": .ColorIndex = wdViolet: End With
  With info(11): .Letter = "I": .ColorIndex = wdBrightGreen: End With
  With info(12): .Letter = "J": .ColorIndex = wdDarkRed: End With
  With info(13): .Letter = "K": .ColorIndex = wdDarkYellow: End With
  With info(14): .Letter = "L": .ColorIndex = wdGreen: End With
  With info(15): .Letter = "M": .ColorIndex = wdPink: End With
  With info(16): .Letter = "N": .ColorIndex = wdGray50: End With
  With info(17): .Letter = "O": .ColorIndex = wdYellow: End With
  With info(18): .Letter = ChrW$(&HD3&): .ColorIndex = wdYellow: End With
  With info(19): .Letter = "P": .ColorIndex = wdBlack: End With
  With info(20): .Letter = "Q": .ColorIndex = wdGray25: End With  'You don't have instructions for this one
  With info(21): .Letter = "R": .ColorIndex = wdViolet: End With
  With info(22): .Letter = "S": .ColorIndex = wdRed: End With
  With info(23): .Letter = "T": .ColorIndex = wdDarkBlue: End With
  With info(24): .Letter = "U": .ColorIndex = wdTurquoise: End With
  With info(25): .Letter = "V": .ColorIndex = wdGray25: End With
  With info(26): .Letter = "W": .ColorIndex = wdPink: End With
  With info(27): .Letter = "X": .ColorIndex = wdYellow: End With
  With info(28): .Letter = "Y": .ColorIndex = wdGreen: End With
  With info(29): .Letter = "Z": .ColorIndex = wdBlack: End With


  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  ColorAllLetters ThisDocument.Range, info, False

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

That took about 80 seconds for 65 pages full of text.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! This didn't work at first it kept saying that this line Public Sub ColorAllLetters(ByVal r As Range, ColorData() As ColorForLetter, ByVal MatchCase As Boolean) was a compile error, but it worked if I ran it as a module. I dunno, anyway, thanks!